# Deploy azure worker role outside of visual studio with diagnostic setting

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-deployment

We are creating the azure worker role deployment package via our ci server and deploy the package to the azure cloud service using Azure Powershell cmdlets script.

however the diagnostic configuration does not get apply to the deployment; it only works when we deploy manually from within visual studio.

is there a way to do that in the powershell script to take into account the diagnostic setting (performance counter..etc) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495270.aspx) PowerShell Cmdlet to enable diagnostics. You may find this link useful for this purpose: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/ (Please see `Step 5: Install Diagnostics on your Worker Role`).